# Windows 7 Multicast Receive Stops Receiving after a few minutes

Tags: sockets, multicast

This is in C++ on Windows 7... I'm sort of a novice Multicast Socket guy, and inherited this code from somebody else.

I've got this system where I have multiple computers creating/joining a multicast socket at ADDR 225.1.1.2 (why not), and once the socket's connected, they periodically "chat" with each other sending various messages. If I start just one computer (call it "A") on the network and have it periodically send out "keepalive" messages once per second, but nothing is being received (no one else connected to the multicast addr), and leave it sit for about 3 minutes, THEN start another computer B, the first computer A doesn't see the broadcast messages from computer B! B is getting no errors sending the packets, and A is giving no errors receiving anything (receive is never called). I don't know how to get notifications if something is shutting down the receive part, or how I'd register for such info.

If I start the two machines relatively close to each other, each machine sees the other one's keepalive packets. Receives happen on both machines. But, again, if I start the 2nd computer > 3 minutes after starting the first one, the first computer's Receive method seems to have gone to sleep, or gone away, or is in a coma, or whatever. No errors generated, but plain won't see machine B's packets. (Plus, I see 3 threads have exited in my debugger output, but they're not threads I've created, they're system threads). But machine B, the one started the most recently, DOES see the keepalive packets from machine A.

here's the socket calls:

```
hSock = WSASocket(
    AF_INET,
    SOCK_DGRAM,
    0,
    NULL,
    0,
    WSA_FLAG_MULTIPOINT_C_LEAF | WSA_FLAG_MULTIPOINT_D_LEAF | WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);

setsockopt(hSock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,(char *) &bVal,sizeof(bVal));
srcIP.sin_family=AF_INET;

// Need to bind to local interface
srcIP.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(("225.1.1.2"); // htonl(INADDR_ANY);
srcIP.sin_port=htons(5555);
bind( hSock,(struct sockaddr FAR *) &srcIP,sizeof(srcIP) );

nIP_TTL=36;
setsockopt(hSock,IPPROTO_IP,IP_MULTICAST_TTL,(char *) &nIP_TTL,sizeof(int));

mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr=inet_addr("225.1.1.2");
mreq.imr_interface.s_addr=inet_addr("225.1.1.2");
setsockopt(hSock,IPPROTO_IP,IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,(char *) &mreq,sizeof(mreq));
```

Here's what I've come across on the internet:

1. The receive buffer could be full. (I don't think so, since Computer A is the only one on the network using multicast)
2. The firewall could set to turn Receive on Multicast off after a few minutes. (I don't believe this)
3. The WinSock protocol could turn receive off for multicast after X minutes of non-activity. (I don't believe this either)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a mistake in your code above. I think you must specify the local IP address of your computers network interface for imr_interface (usually the IP address of your computer,not the multicast address). That is, the interface you want to send/receive multicast traffic on. I assume your code never joined the multicast group at all and it just worked by chance for some time.

Even when you fail to call IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP at all it may work for a couple of minutes.

The strange 3 minute behavior sounds perfectly like a non-working join or an IGMP snooping problem.

IPv4 multicast is very subtle, and the behaviors of hosts, operating systems and inbetween hardware components is are also very subtle.

The operating system sends and receives IGMP messages when your application deals with multicast. This is automatic and relies on correct calls to IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP etc, but except for that you have no control over this. The inbetween hardware components (WLAN routers, switches, Powerline-Adapters, ...) all do magic to make multicast work, and this magic tends to hide problems and to create problems.

One example: If your process calls IP_ADD_MEMBERHIP for multicast address X, then all other processes on the machine will also see multicast traffic from address X, even if they fail to call IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP.

Typical symptoms for a missing (or bogus) ADD_MEMBERSHIP are: It works for a couple of minutes (3 to 5 minutes are typical) and then suddenly stops working, as if the cable was pulled. Restarting one of the programs fixes the problem again, for the next 3-5 minutes. But even with 100% correct ADD_MEMBERSHIP you can have such symptoms when crossing a nontrivial network component like a Powerline-Adapter. Then this is some kind of incompatibility between the OS you are using and the router/switch/adapter you are using.

To debug this try to inspect the IGMP state of your host OS. I do not know how to do this on Windows though.